# How to convert Microsoft Graph Message to Aspose MailMessage?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, aspose, aspose.email

Via Graph, i fetch a Message. I wish to convert this to a MailMessage, so I can fit it into our existing code. Is there any SDK or frameworks that enables this functionality?

I tried to make a method myself for converting, however, I ran into a bunch of problems, as its not possible to directly convert all of the attributes (subject, attachments, from, etc.).